# Authorization failed : Unexpected end of input in Response While Fetching data from API

Tags: javascript, request

I am fetching data from API in js, but it is gives error.

```
<button onclick="event.preventDefault(); getOdds()">Print odds</button>
```

**JS**

```
function getOdds() {
   const sportsKey = prompt("Enter the sports key:");
   const region = prompt("Enter the region (choices = uk, us, us2, eu, au):");
   const market = prompt("Enter the market (choices = h2h, spreads, totals, outrights):");
   const apiKey = 'APIKEY';
   let headers = new Headers();

   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
   headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
   headers.append('GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS');
   headers.append('apikey','apikey');

 fetch('https://apiurl/'+sportsKey+'/odds?apiKey='+apiKey+'&regions='+region+'&markets='+market+'', {
  mode: 'no-cors',
  credentials: 'include',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: headers
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.log(json))
.catch(error => console.log('Authorization failed : ' + error.message));
}
```

When I click button print odds I gives me this error:

> Authorization failed : Unexpected end of input

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try these steps

Step 1:

I guess, the problem is that the response you're getting is not a valid json ( maybe null ).

In this case, try this

```
fetch('https://apiurl/'+sportsKey+'/odds?apiKey='+apiKey+'&regions='+region+'&markets='+market+'', {
  mode: 'no-cors',
  credentials: 'include',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: headers
})
.then(response => {
  return response.text()
})
.then((data) => {
  resolve(data ? JSON.parse(data) : {})
})
.catch((error) => {
  reject(error)
})
```

Gettting the text doesn't give the error even with the empty body. Then check if data exists and resolve. I hope it helps :-)

Step 2 :

If step 1 doesn't work, try changing the mode to 'cors'

```
fetch('https://apiurl/'+sportsKey+'/odds?apiKey='+apiKey+'&regions='+region+'&markets='+market+'', {
  mode: 'cors', // change here 
  credentials: 'include',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: headers
})
```

Hope this answers your question :)

Comment: can you check the content of data?
console.log(data)

Comment: Shouldn't you put html+='</ul> outside forEach loop.

like this 
data.forEach( sport => { 
            console.log(sport)
            html += '<li><strong>'+sport.title+'</strong> ('+sport.key+')</li>'; 
        });
        html += '</ul>';

Comment: I am sorryy actually i am getting this response from api Promise {<fulfilled>: ''}

Comment: when i  expand this it looks like this [[Prototype]]
: 
Promise
catch
: 
ƒ catch()
length
: 
1
name
: 
"catch"
arguments
: 
(...)
caller
: 
(...)
[[Prototype]]
: 
ƒ ()
[[Scopes]]
: 
Scopes[0]
constructor
: 
ƒ Promise()
finally
: 
ƒ finally()

Comment: can you please be clear??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254709/discussion-between-hamza-zafeer-and-syed-shahid-s).